# Set time to watch the player jwplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I working on an idea, I want a person only has 10 minutes to watch the player (jwplayer) I made a script that limits the video to catch, but not quite what I want, the system is the same as the old megavideos .

```
<script>
function list(){
    a = document.getElementById('container');
    b = document.getElementById('erro_msg');
    $('#video-slider').load('updating.php');
    a.style.display = 'none';
    b.style.display = 'block';

}
jwplayer("container").setup({
    width:629,
    height:353,
    primary: "flash",

    allowscriptaccess: "always",
    allowfullscreen: true,

            events:{
            onTime: function(event) {
        if (event.position >= 5600) {
            this.stop();
            list();
    } }
    },


  playlist: [{
      image: "admin/uploads/snapshots/1563283b5af1a859ddd46c1919368bec.jpg",
    sources: [{
      file: "admin/uploads/I_love_you_beth_cooper.mp4",
      label: "360p"
    },{
      file: "admin/uploads/I_love_you_beth_cooper.flv",
      label: "240p"
    }]
  }],  
        });

 </script>
```

this script send a message when the time passed, but as you can see, just have a limit in the case should be 10 minutes to the total irrespective of how many videos you watch.

Comment: I see what the issue is. One idea, would be to use built in Date functions of JavaScript, so that way it won't let you keep watching 10 minutes, or, alternatively, use PHP to log the total time per IP or something along those lines, instead of using JavaScript entirely for this sort of a project.